# mod_jk and load balancing '.method'

Tags: mod-jk

Apache 2.2.3, mod_jk 1.2.37 in front of jboss eap 6. 

In my JKWorkersFile I specify 'worker.list=' with all my loadbalancers. 

Everything seems to work - I can 
change '.host=' or '.port=' setting for a node, or 
change a loadbalancers '.balance_workers=' setting to different nodes. 
My loadbalancers are sticky - and that part works. 
But the log persistently shows my loadbalancers are 
   using method 'Request' 
regardless of my loadbalancers '.method=' setting. 

I found a reference in the download 
(0/r="Requests", 1/t="Traffic", 2/b="Busyness", 3/s="Sessions", 4/n="Next"; case insensitive, only first character is used) 

Has anyone successfully used a '.method=' setting other than 'Request'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. 

User error. 

The workers.properties file I had been given 
contained loadbalancer entries that were not case consistent... 

`worker.loadbalancerPartition1.`*<property>* 
`worker.loadBalancerPartition1.`*<property>* 
`-----------^`